# Static Variables not retaining their values inside function

Tags: c, static-variables

Inside functions static variables retain their value when called again but why it is not happening in this case ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(void) {
    static int x;
    x = 10;
    x += 5;
    printf("%d ", x);
}

int main() {
    print();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving output as `15 15`.

Comment: You reset as `x=10;` each call.

Comment: C book urgently needed

Answer (score 8):

You assign a new value each time:

```
static int x;
x = 10;             // <- assignment
```

What you probably want is initialization:

```
static int x = 10;  // <- initialization
```

Initialization happens only **once** during variable lifetime, and `static` means the variable lives for the whole execution time of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing static variable will solve the issue. Below corrected example resolves the issue and gives me `15` and `20`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(void) {
    static int x = 10; //Initialize here
   // x = 10;  //remove this statement
    x += 5;
    printf("%d ", x);
}

int main() {
    print();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```